# Tensorflow using too much memory when building and training RNN

Tags: python, tensorflow, optimization, recurrent-neural-network

I have built a nonstandard RNN in tensorflow, when I try training it, it uses too much memory. Just building the network uses 1GB, and memory usesage goes upto 5GB when training. It is also very slow.

The network uses 200 floats for it's internal state, but at each step only 100 of these are used as input to the network (the rule for selecting these is not a part of the network), so I'm modeling this by taking the 100 values from the tensor, then using tf.stack to recombine them. The output to the network is then combined with the 100 values that weren't used as input, using another tf.stack.

```
import tensorflow as tf
from random import sample, random


def weight_variable(shape):
    initial = tf.truncated_normal(shape, stddev=0.1)
    return tf.Variable(initial, dtype=tf.float32)


def bias_variable(shape):
    initial = tf.constant(0.1, shape=shape)
    return tf.Variable(initial, dtype=tf.float32)


def run():
    sess = tf.Session()
    W0 = weight_variable((100, 200))
    B0 = bias_variable([200])
    W1 = weight_variable((200, 200))
    B1 = bias_variable([200])
    W2 = weight_variable((200, 100))
    B2 = bias_variable([100])

    memory = tf.constant(0, tf.float32, (200,))
    outputs = []
    correct_outputs = []

    for i in range(40):
        indexes = sample(range(200), 100)
        memory_selection = [memory[z] for z in indexes]
        S = tf.stack(memory_selection, axis=0)
        S = tf.stack([S], axis=0)
        Input = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(S, W0) + B0)
        Hidden = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(Input, W1) + B1)
        Output = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(Hidden, W2) + B2)
        memory_output = []
        used = 0
        for z in range(200):
            if z in indexes:
                memory_output.append(Output[0][used])
                used += 1
            else:
                memory_output.append(memory[z])
        memory = tf.stack(memory_output, axis=0)
        outputs.append(Output)
        correct_outputs.append([random() for _ in range(100)])

    print("Network Built")

    outputs = tf.stack(outputs, axis=0)
    correct_outputs = tf.constant(correct_outputs)
    loss = tf.nn.l2_loss(outputs-correct_outputs)
    optimiser = tf.contrib.optimizer_v2.AdamOptimizer(0.0001)
    train = optimiser.minimize(loss)
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    print("Variables Initialized")
    sess.run(train)
    print("Trained")


run()
```

I end up with an unrolled network 40 steps long.
Could the stack and unstacking be causing the memory problems?
Most of the time is spent in gradients_impl.py, in gradients.

Edit: I have rewritten the above code in PyTorch, and it runs much faster, in less than a second, compared to the minutes tensorflow takes.